# Keep constant spaces for pen DashStyle when zooming

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I am implementing drawing on control in C# using Graphics class. I need to implement zoom feature, but I noticed strange behavior for dashed lines. When I zoom them in, spaces between dashes change, even if pen width does not.

I add a sample code to draw a horizontal dashed line in the middle of a PictureBox, changing zoom level by clicking button1 or button2. Pen is initialized as below:

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Aqua, 8f);
pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.DashDot;
```

Changing zoom level:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  scale *= 2f;
  pictureBox1.Refresh();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  scale /= 2f;
  pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
```

Refreshing PictureBox:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
  pen.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 0, this.pictureBox1.Width/scale, this.pictureBox1.Height/scale));
  e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 0, this.pictureBox1.Height / (2 * scale), this.pictureBox1.Width / scale, this.pictureBox1.Height / (2 * scale));
}
```

Pen is transformed to keep width constant for different zoom levels, but spaces between dashes still change.

Is there a way to keep them constant regardless of zoom?

Comment: You can set the spaces separately from the pen with: Simply update the numbers in the [dashpattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pen.dashpattern?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: To be sure, I shall check it tomorrow and post an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the dashes and spaces constant when scaling the graphics object you need to remove the scaling from the pen's [`DashPattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pen.dashpattern?view=netframework-4.7.2) numbers.

Here is an example:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen1, 0, 40, 600, 40);  // black line

float scale = 2.5f;

e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

pen2.DashPattern = pen2.DashPattern.Select(x => x / scale).ToArray();

e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen2, 0, 30, 600, 30);  // pink line
```

Result

[image]

No need to scale the pen unless you want to remove the scaling from the width as well, btw! But if you want to keep width constant, you need to scale by `1f/scale` as well; your code has it go in the same direction as the `Graphics.ScaleTransform` which will multiply the effect!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep constant visual pen size (width and spaces) regardless of scale you can counter scale pen width and replace line:

```
pen.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
```

with:

```
pen.Width = 8f / scale; //8f is initial pen width for scale = 1
```

That way will line remain the same all the time.

Comment: If I set initial width to 1, dash still changes. For the initial width of 8 it also doesn't work if scale is big/small enough - perhaps there is an internal issue with precision/rounding in GDI+ and I need to disable transform other than start/end points?

Comment: Sadly I did not. If pen width is set close to one (not only one) it behaves differently than for bigger numbers. I did not have time to explore further for arithmetic details of implementation.

Comment: Whoops I misplaced the question; sorry. OP doesn't use tiny pen width but zooms in from 8f, btw..